# Regex end of line replace

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to replace the end of a line on line with ';' but only on lines that do not already end in ';'.  I came up with the following to put in the replace dialog:

```
Find What = '[^\;]\r\n' 

Replace with = '\;\r\n'
```

My problem is that this also selects the last character of a line.  I don't want to replace the last character... just the carriage return.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: try using capture groups: Find: `(.*)([^\;])(\r\n)` Replace: `\1\;\3`

Comment: Frank: quick perusal of the first couple hundred lines of the 25k line file I have is showing that it seems to have done the trick.  Thanks.  If you will do this as a reply I will mark it at the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex as it stands will replace the whole end of the line, so the best bet is to take the whole line, check it for a semi, and only replace the section that needs it (eg add a semi).

```
(.*)([^\;])(\r\n)
```

is an expression with 3 capture groups:

- `(.*)` -- the first part of the line
- `([^\;])` -- the check for the missing semi
- `(\r\n)`  -- the line ending

So, we can take the first group, add a semi, and then take the last group to get the full line, with the only difference being the semi itself.

the replace expression `\1\;\3` will concatenate together the first group, a semi, and the last group.

Note that the `\#` syntax is common to Notepad++ and some other tools, but is not universal (many use $1, $2,...$n). be sure to check your editors documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Find What: ([^\;])\r\n
Replace with: $1;\r\n
```

It will replace the last character with the same character + ';' unless it is ';'

Also, in 'replace' '\' is not needed before ';'

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!;)$`
- Replace with: `;`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!        # negative lookbehind, zero-length assertion that make sure we haven't before current position:
    ;       # a semicolon
)           # end lookbehind
$           # end of line
```